# Prism Library 5.0 for WPF 利用環境にて、”参照されていないアセンブリで定義” ビルドエラー

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

.NET 4.5.2 + Prism Library 5.0 for WPF の環境にて、 
`Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase` を継承したクラスを作成したところ、
下のビルドエラーが特定の環境で発生するようになりました。

> エラー   1   型 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged' が参照されていないアセンブリで定義されています。アセンブリ 'System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' への参照を追加してください。

クラスの中身は何も書かれておらず、クラス名の部分に波線のエラー表示が出ます。

3つの環境でテストし、1台の PC でのみエラーになってしまいます。  
3台の PC の環境はどれも Windows 8.1 64bit Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 です。

原因が分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

Comment: プロジェクトの参照設定に**System**が含まれていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 
 Systemは含まれています。  
試しにWPFアプリケーションプロジェクトを新規で作成し、NugetでPrism.Mvvmを追加  
クラスの新規作成で、BindableBaseを継承したところ同じくエラーになってしまいました。  
VisualStudio2013を再インストールしてみましたが症状は変わらず。  
.net frameeworkも入れ直してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack  
.NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack  
の二つを再インストールしたところ、エラーは発生しなくなりました。